# Force pgfplots to draw legend according to cycle list instead of the first plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot, legend

I use pgfplots to plot multiple curves from a file. The graph is plotted in two steps

1. Draw only the marks, taking the original values from the file
2. Draw only the lines, approximating the curve of the values with gnuplot

So it looks something like this (the following only illustrates the reason why I face this problem):

```
\foreach \r in {1,...,9} { % first loop, marks
    \addplot+[only marks]
        plot table [x index=0, y index=\r]{file.csv};
}
\foreach \rg in {2,...,10} { % second loop, lines (gnu starts with 1)
    \addplot+[no markers]
        gnuplot [raw gnuplot]
            {
                f(x)=a*x+b;
                a=1; b=0.1;
                fit f(x) 'file.csv' using 1:\rg\space every ::1 via a;
                plot [x=0:10] f(x);
            };
}
```

Now the problem is that pgfplot seems to use the style of the first few plots it comes across. This leaves all legend entries without lines since the style of the first plots is only marks.

Therefore, the following MWE produces an output like this, leaving the legend entries without lines:[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycyclelist}{
    {loosely dashed, blue}, {red}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[cycle list name = mycyclelist, legend entries={a, b}, legend pos=north west]
    % only marks
        \addplot+[only marks]
        coordinates
        {
            (0,0)
            (10,5)
        };
        \addplot+[only marks]
        coordinates
        {
            (0,0)
            (10,7)
        };

        % no markers
        \addplot+[no markers]
        coordinates
        {
            (0,0)
            (10,5)
        };
        \addplot+[no markers]
        coordinates
        {
            (0,0)
            (10,7)
        };
    \end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `forget plot` to the first two `\addplot`s like `\addplot+[only marks,forget plot]` is OK for you?

Comment: That leaves me with an image where the marks are the same color and the legend does show the lines, but not the marks. What I want is a combination of both, a legend with marks **and** lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option `legend image post style` is precisely what you need:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycyclelist}{
    {loosely dashed, blue}, {red}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
        cycle list name = mycyclelist, 
        legend entries={a, b}, 
        legend pos=north west,
        legend image post style={sharp plot},
        ]
    % only marks
        \addplot+[only marks]
        coordinates
        {
            (0,0)
            (10,5)
        };
        \addplot+[only marks]
        coordinates
        {
            (0,0)
            (10,7)
        };

        % no markers
        \addplot+[no markers]
        coordinates
        {
            (0,0)
            (10,5)
        };
        \addplot+[no markers]
        coordinates
        {
            (0,0)
            (10,7)
        };
    \end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The list of options after `legend image post style` applies to every legend image and is independent of the plot style. Adding `sharp plot` essentially overrides the `only marks` statement - but only for legend images.